# How do I sort this list of tuples by both values?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples: `[(2, Operation.SUBSTITUTED), (1, Operation.DELETED), (2, Operation.INSERTED)]`

I would like to sort this list in 2 ways:

First by its 1st value by ascending value, i.e. `1, 2, 3... etc`
Second by its 2nd value by reverse alphabetical order, i.e. `Operation.SUBSTITITUTED, Operation.INSERTED, Operation, DELETED`

So the above list should be sorted as:

`[(1, Operation.DELETED), (2, Operation.SUBSTITUTED), (2, Operation.INSERTED)]`

How do I go about sort this list?

Answer (score 4):

Since sorting is [guaranteed to be stable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), you can do this in 2 steps:

```
lst = [(2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]

res_int = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
res = sorted(res_int, key=lambda x: x[0])

print(res)

# [(1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]
```

Comment: that's some fair play here :) TBH I think I saw this trick somewhere here some time ago (but where?)

Comment: you should edit your answer to emphasis the fact that it works with any type. Mine doesn't.

Comment: I get this error when trying your solution: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Operation' and 'Operation'`

Comment: @jpp OP question doesn't have a typo. The second parameter is an object _instance_ !!!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, So I'm confused, are we meant to use the *instance name* to sort?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, *because the order of comparison can be easily inverted for integers*, you can sort in one time using negative value for integer key & reverse:

```
lst = [(2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]
res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (-x[0],x[1]), reverse=True)
```

result:

```
[(1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]
```

negating the integer key cancels the "reverse" aspect, only kept for the second string criterion.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. But note, by construction, this is specific to ordering in the 2-item case. If you have ascending / descending / ascending across 3-items, this may not work.

Comment: yes, your solution is more generic. Also, if the tuples were _strings_, that would not work either (because there's no easy way to invert string comparison, maybe prefix by `z` :))

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Operation' and 'Operation'`

Comment: we wrongly thought that your input data second field was a _string_ when it was an object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [(2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]

inter = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
sorted_lst = sorted(inter, key=itemgetter(0))

print(sorted_lst)

# [(1, 'Operation.DELETED'), (2, 'Operation.SUBSTITUTED'), (2, 'Operation.INSERTED')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
d = [(1, 'DELETED'), (2, 'INSERTED'), (2, 'SUBSTITUTED')]
d.sort(key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
d.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
print(d)
```