# Conditional sorting in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

In Python how can i sort a two item list based on the condition: if first items are not equal do a normal sort (based on the values of first items), and if the first items are equal sort base on the biggness of second items (the bigger value comes first):

Keys of a dictonary like this:

```
{(0, 3): (3, 8), (0, 11): (4, 4), (1, 4): (5, 32)}
```

should be then sorted as such:

```
[(0, 11), (0, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: the fact that this is a dictionary is irrelevant here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort this list of tuples by both values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752739/how-do-i-sort-this-list-of-tuples-by-both-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a key function that reverses the sorting of the second elements:

```
d = {(0, 3): (3, 8), (0, 11): (4, 4), (1, 4): (5, 32)}
print(sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda tup: (tup[0], -tup[1])))  # note the minus
# [(0, 11), (0, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: or `sorted(d, ` ... looks like a duplicate to me once the dictionary part is removed

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752932/6451573, that said, the answer solves it, but the question is indeed different.